# Cannot clone an aegir site

Tags: multi-sites, aegir

I am getting this error while cloning the site on aegir

> Unknown option: --profile.  See `drush help provision-backup` for available >options. To suppress this error, add the option --strict=0. [2.39 sec, 21.19 MB]

I am using aegir3 on ubuntu 14.04.4.
Can anyone please help me solve this.
I have searched on web but there is no solution regarding this issue.
This issue also occurs while migrating.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in IRC, the following work-around should resolve that particular issue:

1. Login to the server via ssh.
2. Become the 'aegir' user (`sudo -u aegir -s -H`)
3. Create a file call /var/aegir/.drushrc.php with the following contents:

   ```
    <?php
    $options['strict'] = 0;
   ```

That said, this appears to be a bug, though not one that has been reported previously. If anyone else stumbles across this issue, please file a bug report at https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/provision.

Comment: a possibly related bug report: https://www.drupal.org/node/2557025